# All images in my.resource has been deleted

Tags: vb.net

I have made wrong manipulation all the images in the resource have been deleted. 
I copied and pasted again but now I have errors at all xxxx.designer.vb files.
All lines containing  .Image = Global.blabla.My.Resources.Resources.Resources.xxxx  has  an error.
resources no longer exist.
I wrote the line code again but the word resources doesn't appears in the intellisence 
As a result I can no longer open xxx.vb files (design).
To check I have added a new  windows form and add a button and try  to add an image. I click the image properties I have the panel select resource that appears I check project resource file
there is indeed the list of all the images but there is no image
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's all been fixed.

I tried to understand what error i commited.
Accidentaly i have deleted the folder bin from the solution explorer and this generated all the errors.
I restored the deleted file from the recycle bin